# Space issue about Colab in chrome version 79.0.3945.130

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

[Codes are squeezed together and not showing a space.
Even when I tab it or enter a space.
Same code can show those spaces if pasted in jupyter notebook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u01Q4.png)

[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `chrome://settings/fonts` in the address bar. There, you can adjust the Fixed-width font setting to change the font.